# Create a method on another method in Java

Tags: java

I have 4 arrays:

The first is named `Students` with several students. Then, I have 2 arrays with several notes. And an array `noteFinale` to calculate the average.

```
String[] students = {"Toto", "Titi", "Tata"};
int[] notes1 = {4,11,12};
int[] notes2 = {17,12,14};
int[] noteFinale = new int[3];
```

I have to display the students with the notes:

```
display(students, notes1, notes2);
...

public static void display(String[] tabStudent, int[] tabNote1, int[] tabNote2){

    for(int i=0; i<tabStudent.length; i++){
      System.out.println("-------------------");
      System.out.println("Student " + (i+1) + " : " + tabStudent[i]);
      System.out.println("Note 1 ==> " + tabNote1[i]);
      System.out.println("Note 2 ==> " + tabNote2[i]);
    }

  }
```

I retrieve the students and the notes

```
-------------------
Student 1 : Toto
Note 1 ==> 4
Note 2 ==> 17
-------------------
Student 2 : Titi
Note 1 ==> 11
Note 2 ==> 12
-------------------
Student 3 : Tata
Note 1 ==> 12
Note 2 ==> 14
-------------------
```

Now, I want to calculate the average of the notes...

```
calculeAverage(students, notes1, notes2, noteFinale);
...

public static void calculeAverage(String[] tabStudent, int[] tabNote1, int[] tabNote2, int[] tabFinal){
    
    int count = 2;
    for(int i=0; i<tabFinal.length; i++){
      tabFinal[i] = tabNote1[i] + tabNote2[i];
      tabFinal[i] /= count;
      System.out.println(tabFinal[i]);   
    }

}
```

In the display, I have this:

```
10
11
13
```

I would like to display also the name for each student.

For example:

```
Toto => 10
Titi => 11
Tata => 13
```

I don't understand how to I can called my `calculeAverage()` method inside `display()`?

I thank you in advance for your explanation.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    String[] students = {"Toto", "Titi", "Tata"};
    int[] notes1 = {4,11,12};
    int[] notes2 = {17,12,14};
    int[] noteFinale = new int[3];

    display(students, notes1, notes2);
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    System.out.println("Average notes : ");
    calculeAverage(students, notes1, notes2, noteFinale);
    }

    public static void display(String[] tabStudent, int[] tabNote1, int[] tabNote2){

    for(int i=0; i<tabStudent.length; i++){
      System.out.println("-------------------");
      System.out.println("Student " + (i+1) + " : " + tabStudent[i]);
      System.out.println("Note 1 ==> " + tabNote1[i]);
      System.out.println("Note 2 ==> " + tabNote2[i]);
    }

  }

  public static void calculeAverage(String[] tabStudent, int[] tabNote1, int[] tabNote2, int[] tabFinal){
    
    int count = 2;
    for(int i=0; i<tabFinal.length; i++){
      tabFinal[i] = tabNote1[i] + tabNote2[i];
      tabFinal[i] /= count;
      System.out.println(tabFinal[i]);   
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour eric, welcome!

You do not need to call another method. The students names are in the array `students`. Just read from it like you are doing in the `display` method.

An array is a structure, you need to pass it the index of the data you would like to read (or write).

Comment: Bonjour Pyb, merci beaucoup, I solved my problem `System.out.println(tabStudent[i] + " " + tabFinal[i]);   `

Comment: You're welcome! It's a bit easier to understand when you write your array the same way, i.e. students[0] = "Toto"; students[1] = "Titi"; etc.